# python-elasticsearch: how do you enable curl logging?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logging, instrumentation, elasticsearch-py

I am using python-elasticsearch module, I read in the [python-elasticsearch documentation that you can log all the underlying HTTP requests as command line `curl` commands](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html?highlight=logging#logging):

> elasticsearch.trace can be used to log requests to the server in the
>   form of curl commands using pretty-printed json that can then be
>   executed from command line. Because it is designed to be shared (for
>   example to demonstrate an issue) it also just uses localhost:9200 as
>   the address instead of the actual address of the host. If the trace
>   logger has not been configured already it is set to propagate=False so
>   it needs to be activated separately.

**For python-elasticsearch module, how do you enable this `curl` logging?**

I tried:

- setting the global logger to `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` but that didn't output the curl
- I tried getting the `elasticsearch.trace` logger and setting that logger's level to `logging.DEBUG` and then setting `es_trace_logger.propagate = True` but neither of those worked

Comment: Try initializing the `elasticsearch` logger and set its level to DEBUG

Comment: @Jay so `logger = logging.getLogger('elasticsearch'); logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`? have you tried this and know it works?

Comment: Hmm, the `elasticsearch` logger will only show you the `GET/POST` request and the corresponding response. The `elasticsearch.trace` logger will show the same info in a better manner as a curl request and in prettified json.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think one crucial step which you might be missing is adding a handler to the `elasticsearch.trace` logger.

```
import logging
es_trace_logger = logging.getLogger('elasticsearch.trace')
es_trace_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
es_trace_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

So here I have added a `StreamHandler` to the logger, so all the logs will go to `stdout`. You can add a different handler if needed as per your use case like `FileHandler` for example.

Here is a sample debug log for the same -

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "size": 100
}'
#[200] (1.311s)
#{
#  "_shards": {
#    "failed": 0,
#    "successful": 6,
#    "total": 6
#  },
#  "hits": {
#    "hits": [
#      {
#        "_id": "FLKSD0SDFJJSDF7D518319DE5EEBB5d5b07044",
```

Having this logger will log the whole request and response for every request that we do, so sometimes these logs can be overwhelming, but are pretty good for debugging.

For the same request, the corresponding `elasticsearch` logger will output something like this -

```
GET http://my_es_host:9200/my_index/_search [status:200 request:1.528s]
> {"size": 100}
< {"took":21,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":6,"successful":6,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":112,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"my_index","_
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was simple and very helpful.